# Stripe Checkout Session Not Loading Window

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, stripe-payments

I have a two step register process where a user submits a web form that creates a user record and then redirects them to a Stripe checkout page to store payment information. However, I am not seeing the Stripe Checkout window loaded and seeing this message, `API resolved without sending a response for /api/auth/register, this may result in stalled requests.`

Is there something that is off with how I'm handling the req and res for each step?

**/api/auth/register.ts:**

```
import prisma from '@/libs/client';
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const saltRounds = 10;

  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    if (
      req.body.email &&
      req.body.password &&
      req.body.confirmPassword &&
      req.body.tos
    ) {
      if (req.body.password == req.body.confirmPassword) {
        const registeredUser = await prisma.appUsers.create({
          data: {
            email: req.body.email.toLowerCase(),
            password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, saltRounds),
            termsOfService: req.body.tos,
          },
        });

        const userValues = {
          email: registeredUser.email,
          password: registeredUser.password,
        };

        return fetch(`${req.headers.origin}/api/stripe/checkout`, {
          method: 'POST',
          mode: 'cors',
          cache: 'no-cache',
          credentials: 'same-origin',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          redirect: 'follow',
          referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
          body: JSON.stringify(userValues, null, 2),
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          return res.status(200).json({
            error: 'Password does not match',
          });
        });
      } else {
        return res.status(200).json({
          error: 'Password does not match',
        });
      }
    } else {
      return res.status(200).json({
        error: 'Form not filled in completely',
      });
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(200).json({
      error: 'Server error. We are aware and looking into the issue',
    });
  }
}
```

**/api/stripe/checkout:**

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    console.log(req.body);
    // const plan = req.body.plan;
    const plan = 'starter';
    var pricing;

    switch (plan) {
      case 'starter':
        pricing = process.env.STRIPE_PRICE_ID;
        break;
      default:
        pricing = process.env.STRIPE_PRICE_ID;
    }
    console.log(plan);

    // const { priceId } = req.body;
    const priceId = process.env.STRIPE_PRICE_ID;

    // See https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create
    // for additional parameters to pass.
    try {
      console.log('try - statement');
      console.log(priceId);
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        mode: 'subscription',
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        line_items: [
          {
            price: pricing,
            // For metered billing, do not pass quantity
            quantity: 1,
          },
        ],
        customer_email: req.body.email,
        // {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} is a string literal; do not change it!
        // the actual Session ID is returned in the query parameter when your customer
        // is redirected to the success page.
        success_url: `${req.headers.origin}/app/feed/?ref=checkout-success&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
        cancel_url: `${req.headers.origin}/app/feed/?ref=checkout-skip`,
      });
      console.log(await session);
      console.log('303 redirect');
      res.send({
        sessionId: session.id,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(400);
      return res.send({
        error: {
          message: e.message,
        },
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is redirect the user to Stripe checkout page, according to their [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=node), the response of:

`const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create`

sends back url too, meaning you can send url to the frontend instead id.

```
res.send({
    url: session.url,
});
```

and you can redirect by using useRouter in frontend or `window.location.replace(url)`

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I have tried your idea and have returned a response object to `/api/auth/register.ts:` which makes the call to `/api/stripe/checkout` to create the session, but I can't seem to access this JSON object and key-value pair. The body is `body: { stream: undefined }`

Comment: it's quite weird, can you do some debugging and see what's wrong? and if you can use more async rather than promise hell, like you can get the fetch data using `const response = await fetch()` and the console log data and show if you can get the data. its better for debugging

Comment: Yes, after refactoring the code I was able to get it working. Thank you for the help!